# please explain "back" in the "to hear back"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you explain to me what grammatical work "back" is doing in the following text:

> I sat in the hall thinking. Could Matt's parents be running an illegal cat farm? What is an illegal cat farm? One that kills cats and sells the meat to bad restaurants? (We'd heard **back** when we lived in Chicago that one restaurant near a veterinarian stole sick cats and used the meat. It wasn't true, of course, but it grossed out a lot of people. The restaurant finally closed).

Answer (score 1):

The writer could have used commas to make this clearer:

> "We'd heard, back when we lived in Chicago, that one restaurant...".

That is, it is the same as "**Back** when we lived in Chicago we'd heard that..."

This is not "to hear back", which can mean "to receive a reply".

Answer (score 0):

"Hear back" is an idiomatic way of saying you received a *reply*.

You can say "I heard from my dad" which can mean your dad instigated the contact.

If you say "I heard *back* from my dad" it means that you initially made contact with him, and then he replied to you, perhaps with an answer to a question that you left with him.

It is also used when someone *attempts* to contact someone, perhaps leaves a message for them and then receives a response to the message.

---

**However**, while your quotation *could* mean that, it does not fit the wider context. The quotation is punctuated badly, and probably should read as:

> We'd heard, back when we lived in Chicago, that one restaurant near a veterinarian stole sick cats and used the meat.

The parenthetical commas hopefully make it clearer that the writer heard the statement at a previous time. "Back when..." is an idiomatic way of referring to a previous time period, perhaps marked by specific circumstances, in this case, while he lived in Chicago.

Comment: This is not an example of "hear back", but "heard, back when we were in Chicago", that is, "we heard it in the past when we were in Chicago".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I appreciate your comment to help me correct my answer. I had focused on the question heading rather than the content.

Answer (score 0):

"Back" could also be used to mean *in the past*.

You can say "Back when I lived in New York..." meaning in the past, the speaker use to live in New York.

In your example, it seems as if the speaker is recalling information about a restaurant from when they use to live in Chicago.